# How to find the value in a cell after consecutive positive numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

[image]

I have a list here of numbers, positive and negative, from A3:A17. I want to find the value after a consecutive streak of positive numbers. So in the picture above, there's a streak of two consecutive positive numbers from A5 to A6, 2.60% and 1.10%, respectively. I want to get the number after that, which is -1.90%. But if there's another streak of two positive numbers, I want the formula to be able to identify that too. I have a formula to identify the streak but not one to identify the number that comes after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these in cell B3 (deleting everything below):

Any occurrences:

```
=arrayformula(if(A3:A<0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A>0,A3:A,),),))
```

2 occurrences:

```
=arrayformula({"";if(A4:A<0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A4:A,),),),)})
```

3 occurrences:

```
=arrayformula({"";"";if(A5:A<0,if(A4:A>0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A5:A,),),),),)})
```

4 occurrences:

```
=arrayformula({"";"";"";if(A6:A<0,if(A5:A>0,if(A4:A>0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A6:A,),),),),),)})
```

Comment: This one worked! Thank you so much! Is there a way to change the formula so it only specifically looks for the value after two consecutive positive numbers? and not three or four?

Comment: Try this in cell B3 `=arrayformula({"";if(A4:A<0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A4:A,),),),)})`

Comment: Thanks! Which part of the formula determines that it looks for only 2 consecutive positive numbers? I also want in a separate column, for three consecutive positive numbers, another column with 4 consecutive positive numbers, etc.

Comment: It's a series of successive IF statements. This will do 3: `=arrayformula({"";"";if(A5:A<0,if(A4:A>0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A5:A,),),),),)})` A5:A is the baseline of the check then tests are done for A4:A, A3:A and A2:A being less than 0, and A1:A being greater than 0 (3 sequential negatives). Where the test is true it displays A5:A (the baseline figure). The code runs from B3 and uses `"";"";` to add two returns to check from the baseline of B5:B. For 4, use `=arrayformula({"";"";"";if(A6:A<0,if(A5:A>0,if(A4:A>0,if(A3:A>0,if(A2:A>0,if(A1:A<0,A6:A,),),),),),)})`

Answer (score 1):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF(A3:A>0,IF(A4:A>0,A5:A,),),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell B3 and autofill downward:

```
=IF(A1>0,IF(A2>0,A3,""))
```